# Ordinary differential equationn

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this differential equation:

$x''(t) =-\frac{1}{(x(t)+1)^2}$ with $x(0)=0, x'(0)=0$

why is $x(t)<0$ for $t>0$?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x''(t) =-\frac{1}{(x(t)+1)^2} <0$ for $t \ge 0$, it follows that $x'$ is strictly decreasing. From $x'(0)=0$ we see that $x'(t) <0$ for $t>0$, hence $x$ is strictly decreasing. From $x(0)=0$ we see that $x(t) <0$ for $t>0$.